# Why wordpress home page is blank

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

here is my [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/8f920c5e357ed5197692547fa23b9ff0), I run followng shell to start wordpress

```
sudo nginx -g 'daemon off;' -c /home/roroco/Dropbox/rbs/ro_wp/conf/nginx.wp.conf
```

I can get 200 ok response, but the home page is blank, like follwong, and my nginx error log has no error

[image]

**update**

here is my [wp-config](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ab54ab853b47960133efff61ba61aec3), I only download the latest wordpress and only change this file

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution:

my old nginx.conf is like:

```
...
location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri =404;
fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
# sock file can be found in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
fastcgi_index index.php;
}
...
```

the correct nginx.conf is

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        # sock file can be found in /etc/php/7.0/fpm/pool.d/www.conf
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
}
```